# Loop not displaying comments_popup_link

Tags: comments, loop, php

I cannot get the `comments_popup_link` to display with the posts retrieved by the foreach loop. Only the title and permalink are displayed. Any idea why the comment link is left out?

```
<?php
  if(count($ids)){
    echo '<div id="tab-news" class="tab-all"><a id="link-news" class="link-all" href="/news">News</a></div><ul>';
    foreach($ids as $id){
       echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">'.get_the_title( $id ).'</a>';
       if ( comments_open() ) :
       echo '<p>';
       comments_popup_link( '', '<span class="onecomment">1 comment</span>', '<span class="morecomments">% comments</span>', '');
       echo '</p>';
       endif;
    }
    echo '</li></ul>';
   }
```

Comment: well, it might be stupidly trivial for me to ask, but do you have comments open on the global site configuration ? or maybe disabled on specific posts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [`comments_popup_link()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link) will only work when used within [the_loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop); a 'foreach' loop using post Ids is not the same.

you could try to build your own link, based on this [function: `get_comments_number( $id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_comments_number).

Comment: Thank you! Realized it as well and gave up on the idea and used the normal wordpress loop. The advantage of the foreach loop is that it lets me separate logic and presentation.